# delete record with fetch api in laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am trying to delete a record laravel using fetch api but I get the following error: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: DELETE.

Route:

```
Route::delete('/persona_eliminar/{id}', 'PersonaController@eliminar');
```

button that comes from a foreach where I get the id:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                        onclick="deletePersona({{$persona->id}})">
                        <i class="fas fa-times">
                        </i>
                    </button>
```

Js:

```
function deletePersona(id) {
fetch("/persona_eliminar/" + id, {
    method: "DELETE",
})
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

}

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I personally experienced issues with fetch API also even when using the compatible method for  the route. So instead I use axios, it's pre-installed with the default Laravel frontend.

You could do it this way:

```
axios.delete("/persona_eliminar/" + id)
.then((res) => {
  //
})
```

Here's how I tested it

Route::

```
Route::delete('/bounties/{bounty}/delete', 'BountyController@destroy');
```

Axios demo:

[image]

Comment: I decided to handle the DOM with js vanilla and the requests with axios. It works well. Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Using FormData + Fetch with Laravel and Vue, I got it to work by doing this:

```
let form = new FormData();

form.append("_method", "DELETE");

// append other stuff here

fetch("/api", {
    body: form,
    method: "POST",
 })
```

The key being sending a POST request and a `_method` `DELETE` tag. Sending a DELETE request resulted in a 419 error no matter what I did.

Answer (score 0):

I believe standard syntax is

```
function deletePersona (id) {
  fetch('/persona_eliminar/' + id, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      _method: 'PUT'
    })
  }).then((res) => res.json())
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
    })
}
```

Comment: `method` is the correct syntax,  `_method` is for HTML formdata. eg `formData.append('_method', 'DELETE');`

Comment: Well obviously  it says Get method is not supported it means you sent a GET request to a DELETE route so still I believe method isn't set correctly

Comment: read the [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch)

Answer (score 0):

```
//use url with route
//install axios
//define axios
var axios = require('axios');
  axios({method: 'post',
        url: baseUrl + '/persona_eliminar',
        data: {_token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'), id: id
}
    })
            .then(function (response) {
})
```

Answer (score 0):

edit this code

```
fetch("/persona_eliminar/" + id, {
    method: "DELETE",
})
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

to this:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('_token', "{{ csrf_token() }}");
formData.append('_method', "DELETE");

fetch("/persona_eliminar/" + id, {
    headers:{
           "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
     },
    method: "POST",
    body: formData
})
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
```